# How to make a html page using excel as data source in python

Tags: python, html, pandas

I want to make a simple html page which looks like this:
[image]
The text colored in Orange is the dynamic text. I want to filter the excel table on the webpage and print the specified technology and subTechnology data in the html as output.

```
import pandas as pd
filter = 'LTE2'
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", delimiter=';')
df = df[df['subTechnology'] == filter]
df.to_html('index.html', index=False)
```

With the help of a thoughtful contribution, the df.to_html works well for the data but I still don't know how to deal with the text above the table as shown in the screenshot.

And here is my data source:

```
Technology;subTechnology;Package;Type;Date
4G;LTE2;2.0.5;Major Update;08.10.2017
4G;LTE2;4.4;Normal Update;09.10.2017
2G;GSM2;4.4.2;Major Update;02.12.2017
5G;5G2;1.1.2 mQ1;Major Update;02.01.2020
2G;GSM2A;1.0.7Q;Delivery;03.01.2020
4G;LTE20A;3.0.7;Normal Update;02.03.2020
2G;GSM17A;39142;Major Update;02.04.2020
5G;5G2A;0.2TD;Delivery;03.04.2020
3G;3G20;GF20 2.3;Normal Update;04.04.2020
2G;L2B;1.0TD;Delivery;02.07.2020
5G;5G2A;0.5TD;Delivery;02.08.2020
2G;GSM2B;1.0TD;Delivery;03.08.2020
2G;L2A;1.0.6Q;Delivery;02.10.2020
4G;LTE20A;6.0;Normal Update;02.11.2020
```

I am familiar with tools like xlsx2html and apsose.cells but I don't know how to filter the data as per the specified subTechnology and show only customized excel in the html. Any documentation or suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: What you want is to be able to filter in the website or to filter it locally and the build the website?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a code-writing service - please edit the code of your honest attempt to solve this problem into your question as a [mre] and exalpin what goes wrong/isn't correct about the output. If there's an error message include the _full_ text of this __as text__. Include some minimal sample data in the code.

Comment: @edoelas Ideally I want to be able to filter through the data on the webpage but I assume dealing with the dynamic content on a signle html page can be difficult, so I can even hardcode the "subTechnology" locally and generate the results to html.

Answer (score 1):

You have pandas and python in your tags so I will answer using those technologies.

```py
import pandas as pd

filter = 'LTE2'

# Load data as CSV
df = pd.read_csv("./data.csv", delimiter=';')
# Fitler data
df = df[df['subTechnology'] == filter]
# Save data in HTML format
df.to_html('./output.html', index=False)
```

Comment: Thankyou. Do you also know if there a possibility to be able to select/filter the "subTechnology" in the html page itself?

Comment: I would recommend you to search for a js library that takes care of it. Now I can't think of any but I am sure there are plenty. Please, if my answer helped you mark the answer as accepted.